# Remove a folder if a specific file not exist

Tags: python

For cleaning up my movies data. I want to remove the folder that doesn't have the file with extension ".nfo".

**my code:**

```
movies2 = (r'C:\Users\usph\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Movies2')

extension = '.nfo'

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(movies2):
    for i in files:
        if extension not in i:
            shutil.rmtree(dirpath)
```

The result is not as I expect. All folders were removed!

Please help to correct my code!

Comment: I am assuming you are using Python here? It might be useful to tag the question with the language/framework you are using. That way the question gets picked up more easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, shutil

movies2 = (r'C:\Users\usph\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Movies2')

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(movies2):
    if [f for f in os.listdir(dirpath) if f.endswith('.nfo')] == []:
        try:
            print dirpath
            shutil.rmtree(dirpath)
        except: pass
```